# Cordova in iOS 8 and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I've just updated to Xcode 6 in order to submit my apps for review on the iOS app store and have come across more problems. Please see the image attached! Any help at all would be amazing.

```
Build target CRS

Ld /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Intermediates/CRS.build/Debug-iphoneos/CRS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CRS normal armv7
    cd "/Users/jacbeyportes/Documents/Oasis Websites/Cadet Registration System/Apps/iOS/CRS/platforms/ios"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Intermediates/CRS.build/Debug-iphoneos/CRS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CRS.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -liconv -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Intermediates/CRS.build/Debug-iphoneos/CRS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CRS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Intermediates/CRS.build/Debug-iphoneos/CRS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CRS

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/jacbeyportes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CRS-fydzgpcksptwdjaztipsuhofllde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PushPlugin in PushPlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVBarcodeScanner in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PushPlugin in PushPlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVBarcodeScanner in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
  "_CDVRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PushPlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVBarcodeScanner.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVConnection.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update both Cordova and your plugins.

Here is the news on Cordova moving to 3.6.3
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/09/22/cordova-361.html

Here is the same regarding the plugins that were updated
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/09/22/plugins-release.html

Then update your project
    `cordova platform update ios`

However, I've also run into some issues but it was fixed by removing the platform and adding it again.. You can do that by:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall cordova and reinstall cordova (version 3.6.3). Then I removed the iOS platform from my project folder and readded it. I also removed and re-added each cordova plugin.

It was a pain, but that fixed my compile issues for me.